# Facebook like statistics for socialite

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, statistics, facebook-like

My web page (build with symfony components) has a lot of inner pages that have a like button, which is integrated using socialite.

How can I get like/share statistic overtime, like for the past month/day/year (not the total count but for a period of time) for specific inner pages.

I can get the total count of likes/shares using http://graph.facebook.com/https://my-page.com/some-inner-page

I could make a query that stores this information nightly, but that would take to much resources, because of the high count of inner pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get like/share statistic overtime, like for the past month/day/year (not the total count but for a period of time)

That information is not directly available via API.

Facebook used to offer “Domain Insights,” where you could register your domain and then see some additional metrics for your URLs – but they have stopped this recently, you can not add new domains any more.

> I could make a query that stores this information nightly, but that would take to much resources, because of the high count of inner pages.

It might be your only option though, I’m afraid.

Comment: is it somehow possible to bid the like button event to my google analytics? Maybe it would be a prettier solution?

Comment: You can subscribe to events on the button via the JS SDK - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.7